# Showing that a limit is equal to 0

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits

Let's consider a function
$$f(t) = \frac{t^z}{z} \bigg(e^{-t} - \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-t)^k}{k!} \bigg), \qquad t > 0, \qquad -1-n < \text{Re}(z) < -n.$$

I would like to show that
$$\lim_{t \to 0^+} f(t) = 0.$$

I tried using some standard ways but unfortunately I failed. I would appreciate any hints or tips.

Comment: You mean maybe $e^{-t}$ or sum of the $t^k$?

Comment: @Mindlack I meant $e^{-t}$, sorry! :)

Comment: Then the parts between parentheses is $P(t)=\sum_{k \geq n+1}{\frac{(-t)^k}{k!}}$. Since if $k > n$, $k! \geq (n+1)!(k-n-1)!$, $|P(t)| \leq |t|^{n+1}e^{|t|}$.

Comment: Why $k! \ge (n+1)!(k-n-1)!$?

Comment: $k!/(n+1)!=((n+1)+1)((n+1)+2) \ldots (n+1+(k-n-1)) \geq 1 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot (k-n-1)=(k-n-1)!$.

Comment: @Mindlack, thank you! Can I ask how did you get $\mid t \mid ^{n+1}$? When I wrote the calculations I got only $e^{|t|}$.

Comment: Because you sum the \frac{|t|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\frac{|t|^{k-n-1}}{(k-n-1)!}$ over the $k-n-1 \geq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression in parentheses is $O(t^{n+1}).$ And $|t{^z}| = t^{\text {Re z}}.$ Thus the absolute of the expression equals

$$\frac{1}{|z|}O(t^{n+1-\text {Re z}}) \to 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

As in the proof of [Taylor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem), one can prove by induction and integration by parts,
$$
e^{-x}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-x)^k}{k!}-(-1)^n\int_0^x\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}\,e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag1
$$
Therefore, for $x\ge0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\,e^{-x}-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-x)^k}{k!}\,\right|
&=\int_0^x\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}\,e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&\le\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\tag2
\end{align}
$$